# Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query. i am using ajax toolkit

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I have a problem inserting data into the SQL Server 2008 database.
The `date` column has data type `datetime`. I am using ajax toolkit for calender extender

My code:

```
Doj = textbox12.Text.ToString();
conn.Open();

cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Doctor(Doctor_ID,Doctor_Reg_No,Doctor_FName,Doctor_MName,Doctor_LName,Doctor_Gender, Doctor_Address1, Doctor_Address2, Doctor_Landline, Doctor_Mobile1,Doctor_Mobile2,Doctor_Specialization,Doctor_Join_Date, Doctor_Department_ID) VALUES (@dID,@doc_re,@dfName,@dMN,@dLN,@dG,@da1,@da2,@d_con,@d_mo1,@d_mo2,@d_sp,@d_jo,@dept_id) ";

//converting Doj into sqldbtype for the sql injections     
cmd.Parameters.Add("@d_jo", sqlDbType: System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Doj.Trim();

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is the type of `Doctor_Join_Date` column? Looks like you didn't choose the right data type for your value. Read: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: @SonerGönül data type is datetime for     ' Doctor_Join_Date' i am using same coding for other tables with same datatype and all but here it giving error

Comment: If it is `datetime`, why did you write `SqlDbType.VarChar` as a db type? And why do you want to insert string as `Doj.Trim()`?

Comment: Can you include some sample data that causes the error? What is the value of Doj when you debug?

Comment: Doj is string type variable holds value null at the initial stage when i debug it gets value whatever date i insert in the textbox12

Comment: @SonerGönül i was using SqlDbType.DateTime but it was giving me error while saving data in to database so i am using varchar (it was working fine till now) and Doj.trim() using for remove the spaces.